# How can i display a 3x3 grid in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, set

For a program i intend to develop, its essential for me to develop a 3x3 grid which will display words from a set which has been converted to a list. To achieve this I'm aware of a method which will supposedly create a 3x3 grid using a list with linebreaks already within the developed list. However, my program functions at a more diverse level and instead of having a pre-defined text file / list, my set/list is defined by the users input and utalises a file dialog which allows the user to select their own 9 words for the 3x3 grid. For this reason i dont think its possible to apply the line breaks. Is there another way i could display a 3x3 grid which displays each of these 9 words.  Would be extremely grateful of any advice given. As for code... if anyone feels that any particular section of code would help them solve this problem, do not hesitate to leave a comment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a 3x3 grid is no more difficult than looping over items and creating widgets.

This creates a 3x3 grid of labels, storing references to the widgets in a dictionary:

```
table = tk.Frame(root)
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        label = tk.Label(table, text="")
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        table[(row, col)] = label
```

You can then modify any of the cells of the table using the `configure` method of the label widget. For example, this sets the middle cell to "Hello":

```
table[(1,1)].configure(text="Hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

oyoy, i see dis,

```
table = tk.Frame(root)
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        label = tk.Label(table, text="")
        label.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        table[(row, col)] = label
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)